# loadByAttribute don't list disabled product

Tags: plugins, magento2

I'm writing a plugin to load a product with an attribute name, but this plugin loads only the enabled product, yet I need disabled product as well

> $p = $product->loadByAttribute($att, $attid);

Comment: can you put how you get $product collection before this $p = $product->loadByAttribute($att, $attid); ?

Comment: i used productfactory
$this->productFactory = \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
$product = $this->productFactory->create();

Comment: you want to load product using attribute am I right?

Comment: yes, not only Enabled Product, but also Disabled product.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the products by dependancy injection of collection

```
public function __construct(
            ...
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
            ...
            ) 
{
     ...
     $this->productCollectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
     ...
}
```

and load your data like this

```
$productcollection = $this->productCollectionFactory
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute code', 'option id');
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that, without any applied filter, the number of products in the collection is smaller than the products that I have in Magento db. :(

Comment: is all product enable?